# Material stacks

Tags: image, path

I am having a scene which I'm using to visualize a stage screen setup. I have 7 screens (planes with image texture) in the scene, and I would like to save the image texture paths / material properties of all the objects, be able to save multiple "stacks" of those material options and recall them.

Is there a way?
Cheers

Comment: Hi. Could you edit the question and share some screenshots maybe? This is also not something that is usually done so it seems like this could potentially be [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Could you provide more context about what exactly you are trying to achieve? What is this for? What is the end goal? Are you trying to make some sort of animation? It might be that this is done some other way from the start. For example it's possible to animate mix factor of a few shaders in a material for them to change during animation.

Comment: Hi! I would need to view and explore the blender scene which contains multiple cameras, w. animations and plates with image textures representing "screens". I would use blender as a live visuatization tool to show the customer how the stage setup works and how does the "screen" content look like from different camera angles. I am also rendering out screenshots using multiple cameras / stereoscopic setup and saving stills for review. Hence, I would need to be able save and recall multiple different texture sets, to change the "screen" content. As this is a client project I cannot share content.

Comment: There are many different ways to set it up depending on situation. It is difficult to advice without going into more detail about the situation. If you need a lot of screens of a presentation it could be logical to set them up as an animation with every frame representing a screen.  You can animate object visibility or material properties and bind cameras to timeline markers for them to change. Might make sense to use Constant interpolation between keyframes in that case. You can set it as default in Preferences, Animation tab, F-curve panel for convenience.